# how to optimize renderspeed in android webview

Tags: javascript, android, optimization, webview, rendering

Is there a possibility to enhance the rendering speed in webview? With a simple innerHTML it takes close to 1 sec to display the content although the js rendering takes a few ms. With IOS, exactly the same code is running swiftly and perfectly, even with less performant hardware.

Tested under Android: 2.3, 3.2, 4.0 (Desire HD, Galaxy Nexus, Galaxy Tab)
IOS: 4, 5 (iPhones 3gs, 4)

Appreciate any helpful responses!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There are a few things you can try:

- Turn on hardware acceleration by adding `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` to the application or activity tag in the Android manifest file.  More info here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html
- Modify the RenderPriority of the webview - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.RenderPriority.html
- Optimize your javaScript and CSS to minimize the number of reflows, memory used, and DOM size - http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/mobifying.html#toc-optimizations

Personally, I found that keeping the DOM as small as possible, and enabling hardware acceleration made all of the difference between an unusable app, and a fairly smooth app.

Comment: This just bailed me out. Spent 14 hours on a Saturday recoding my app with some fancy animations only to find out it was terribly slow on a device. `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` and it's a whoooooole lot better. Time not wasted!

Comment: Modify the RenderPriority of the webview - has been deprecated

Comment: So helpfully thanks man, quick question how do set the RenderPriority? And what would be the best settings